# Docker compose gitlab failed

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab

I tried to install Gitlab with docker compose. I set docker-compose.

`gitlab:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  volumes:
    - '/srv/docker/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    - '/srv/docker/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/srv/docker/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
  ports:
    - "10080:10080"
    - "10443:443"
    - "10022:22"
  restart: always
  hostname: '1.1.1.1' 
  dns:
    - xx.xx.xx.xx
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      gitlab_rails['gravatar_enabled'] = false
      gitlab_rails['time_zone'] = 'Asia/Tokyo'`

When I run docker-compose up it failed said

`gitlab_1  | If this container fails to start due to permission problems try to fix it by executing:
gitlab_1  |
gitlab_1  |   docker exec -it gitlab update-permissions
gitlab_1  |   docker restart gitlab
gitlab_1  |
gitlab_1  | Installing gitlab.rb config...
gitlab_1  | cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb': Permission denied
gitlab_gitlab_1 exited with code 1`

as written I tried to run

```
docker exec -it gitlab update-permissions
```

But error said
`Error response from daemon: No such container: gitlab`

Anyone can help?

Just info `docker ps`

Result:

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND             CREATED
xxxxxxx        gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest   "/assets/wrapper"   24 hours ago

And permission file

`ls -la /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`

-rw-------. 1 root root 0 Dec 12 17:00 /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the container doesn't have the permission to create files beneath your mounted volumes:

- `/srv/docker/gitlab/data`
- `/srv/docker/gitlab/config`
- `/srv/docker/gitlab/logs`

The file permissions show that `gitlab.rb` is only read and writeable by `root`. I just checked them - my container uses the same permissions.

So it might be a problem with your Docker host. Somehow it prevents you from creating/writing these files. Maybe the filesystem is mount readonly, or the permissions of the host volume folders don't allow it.
SELinux or App Armour also could be a problem!

I'd recommend to remove all files in the volumes and set the permissions of the 3 folders to `777`. After it started you'll see which user/group ids are needed and you can tighten it down.

Do you use AppArmour, SELinux? What kind of Host OS do you use?

Comment: Dear @Marvin thank you for your response. All 3 folders have same permissions
`drwxr-xr-x. `

I tried to change all permission like you said with 777, but still same error.
I use RedHat 7.4 OS. Any other suggestions?

Comment: if you use redhat selinux could be a problem - maybe selinux logs show that access is prevented

Answer (score 0):

Finally I tried to change content inside docker-compose.yml
I didn't know the exact reason why not worked. Maybe different setting in  gitlab_omnibus

For docker compose I refer to this
[docker-compose.yml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/master/docker-compose.yml)

I deleted existed docker image and container, then run docker-compose. And it works fine

Answer (score 0):

i've the same problem and running this has solved my problem; because i was on SELinux:

```
sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname gitlab.example.com \
  --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab:Z \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab:Z \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab:Z \
  --shm-size 256m \
  gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest
```

This will ensure that the Docker process has enough permissions to create the configuration files in the mounted volumes.

Comment: also you should define another port for ssh if you use this code on change the port of the git